# Interpolating nested values from a scope variable in a view

Tags: angularjs, view, interpolation

So I have the following view:

```
<p type="text" disabled='true' class="form-control" >
  {{selected.timerange}}
</p>
```

The value of `$scope.selected.timerange` is:
`{"available":false,"schedule_start_at":"2015-03-13T00:30:00","schedule_end_at":"2015-03-13T01:00:00"}`

This works fine, but when I use the following view:

```
<p type="text" disabled='true' class="form-control">
  {{selected.timerange.schedule_start_at}}
</p>
```

the interpolation does not happen.
I'm unable to figure out why. Any help please?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Can you create a plnkr/fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your example works if you correctly set up angular. **See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9a1bbny/1/)**

Make sure that :

- The controller that is responsible for the second view is the same instance that the one responsible for the first view. If you instantiated the controller with the `ngController` directive, the instantiation should be on a common parent for both views.

---

*By the way*, please note that boostrap `form-control` class is usually for `input` elements, not for paragraphs.

**Consider replacing :**

```
<p type="text" disabled='true' class="form-control" >
    {{selected.timerange}}
</p>
```

**with :**

```
<input type="text" disabled='true' class="form-control" value="{{selected.timerange}}"/>
```

Comment: Yes I know about input tags. I was just printing out values so used a p tag. Looks like the problem is a string parsed as json.. exploring it.. will keep you posted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here but in case anyone else runs into this issue:

Try initializing your `timerange` variable in the constructor.

`this.selected.timerange = {}` if that doesn't work go one step deeper

`this.selected.timerange.schedule_start_at = ""` (keeping the init from above)

Not sure the philosophy behind this, but I guess it has something to do with observables and/or promises if thats how you're getting your variables ( that was the issue in my case at least )